# How do i send a jtextfield on netbeans into an array

Tags: java, netbeans

```
String[][] EmployeeArray = new String [1000][25];  //array
EmployeeForm1.EmployeeArray.getText(Firstname);   //code to send to array
```

this is what ive been trying but i get an error and i don't know how to fix employeeform1 is the class name

Comment: what is `EmployeeForm1` ?

Comment: There is no way to help you with this so unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

How to you add any value into an Array?

You define the array:

```
String[] text = new String[10];
```

Then you add a String to it:

```
text[0] = "someText";
```

Using a text field is not different except you use the getText() method of the text field:

```
text[1] = textField.getText();
```

If the get text field is defined in your EmployeeForm then you should use a getter method:

```
text[2] = employeeForm.getFirstName();
```

Where getFirstName() is a method that invokes the getText() method on the text field that contains the first name.